# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct libnet_ip_hdr'

Tags: c, gcc

При обращении к какому либо-элементу структуры libnet_ip_hdr компилятор выдает ошибку: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct libnet_ip_hdr'. При этом на структуру libnet_tcp_hdr компилятор не ругается. компилирую так: gcc rst.c -o rst -g `libnet-config --libs` `libnet-config --defines` -l pcap

```
void callback(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *cap_header, const u_char *packet) {

    struct libnet_ip_hdr *IPhdr;
    struct libnet_tcp_hdr *TCPhdr;
    TCPhdr->th_sport;
    IPhdr->ip_src; 
}
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: the pointers have not been initialized to point to memory that the application owns.

Comment: `IPhdr = (struct libnet_ip_hdr *)(packet + LIBNET_ETH_H);` 
`TCPhdr = (struct libnet_tcp_hdr *)(packet + LIBNET_ETH_H + LIBNET_TCP_H);` do you mean? it doesn't help

Comment: I mean: call `malloc` to allocate some heap memory for each pointer, similar to: `struct libnet_ip_hdr *IPhdr = malloc( sizeof( struct libnet_ip_hdr );`  the statement: `TCPhdr->th_sport;` does nothing.  I suspect it should be: `TCPhdr->th_sport = 'the source for the port number';

Comment: @user3629249: В вопросе же ясно сказано, что ошибка возникает *при компиляции*. И никакого `malloc` тут сделать не получится: невозможно сделать `sizeof( struct libnet_ip_hdr )` если `struct libnet_ip_hdr` является неполным типом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема именно в том, что вам сказал компилятор. Тип `struct libnet_ip_hdr` до функции `callback` у вас в программе не объявлен вообще. Ваше

```
struct libnet_ip_hdr *IPhdr;
```

фактически объявляет его как новый тип, локальный в функции `callback`. То есть с точки зрения компилятора, вы сами только что выдумали тип `struct libnet_ip_hdr` и ввели его в обращение внутри функции `callback`. Объявленный таким образом тип является неполным и доступаться к его полям вы не можете. Вы никаких полей в нем и не объявили.

Если это тип из какой-то посторонней библиотеки (и если по замыслу авторов этой библиотеки у вас должен быть прямой доступ к содержимому `struct libnet_ip_hdr`), что очевидно, вы просто не включили в свой код заголовочный файл с определением этого типа.

Comment: Включен файл `libnet.h`. Определения  `struct libnet_ip_hdr ` и `struct libnet_tcp_hdr ` находятся в одном и том же заголовочном файле и при этом я могу обратиться ко второй структуре, так что  видимо проблема не в библиотеке

Comment: @Антон: Ну магии не бывает. Еще раз: сообщения компилятор однозначно указывает, что такого типа не объявлялось. Дайте ссылку на текст вашего `libnet.h` - будем смотреть.

Comment: @Антон: Например, вот здесь - https://github.com/sam-github/libnet/blob/master/libnet/include/libnet/libnet-headers.h - нет никакого `struct libnet_ip_hdr`. С чего вы взяли, что он вообще должен существовать?

Comment: Обьявил как struct libnet_ipv4_hdr - все работает. Странно что у меня в libnet-headers.h он обьявлен как libnet_ip_hdr. Спасибо.